# How to run cypress tests at a particular time of the day?

Tags: time, cypress, schedule

I want to run a cypress test at a particular time of a day or I want to schedule the test to run every 30 minutes for example. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way to do this would be to deploy your tests to a server and run them on some sort of cron job.  You could do this locally, as well, but it makes the most sense to run them inside of a container or virtual server.

Hope this helps, let us know how it goes!